# EF Core base entity class inheritance and readonly properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-core

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity : IEntity
{
    private Guid _id;
    private DateTime _createdOn;
    private DateTime _modifiedOn;
    private byte[] _timestamp;

    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id => _id;

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public DateTime CreatedOn => _createdOn;

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public DateTime ModifiedOn => _modifiedOn;

    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] Timestamp => _timestamp;
}
```

This is base class, all entities should inherit from this class. Also this properties should be readonly (I'm using [backing properties](http://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modeling/backing-field.html)), because EF need to take care of them.

```
public class Category : BaseEntity
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And `OnModelCreating` is empty.
When I run migrations, I get message :

> 'The entity type 'Project.Database.Models.Category' requires a primary
>   key to be defined.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your BaseEntity.Id property is read only.

Your Id property is implemented as an [expression-bodied member](https://davefancher.com/2014/08/25/c-6-0-expression-bodied-members/) (the => syntax), which is merely syntactic sugar for a get-only property.

So, your code:

```
public Guid Id => _id;
```

is equivalent to:

```
public Guid Id { get { return _id; } }
```

EF must be able to set the values of mapped properties. You'll have to use traditional syntax to implement the property, and you'll have to provide a setter.  If your context is in the same assembly as your model, you could mark the setter as internal so that the property is read only outside the assembly.  If your context is in a different assembly, you could still mark the setter as internal, then use the [InternalsVisibleTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) attribute to make internals visible to the assembly containing your context.

Comment: Shouldn't this be handled with backing fields. Then where backing fields should be used?

Comment: The backing field is _id, which is being used in both method implementations.  The backing field is not what is mapped to the database column, though.  The property is.  The backing field is just a private mechanism inside your model class that the Entity Framework (and everyting else as well) knows/cares nothing about.

Comment: Backing field is set when object is created, property is what EF map to database. I still don't understand why this doesn't work.
"When a backing field is configured, EF will write directly to that field when materializing entity instances from the database (rather than using the property setter). This is useful when there is no property setter, or the setter contains logic that should not be executed when setting initial property values for existing entities being loaded from the database." - From ef core docs

Comment: But your syntax doesn't match the example for a backing field that will be discovered by convention.  Have you tried not using the expression-bodied syntax?  Have you tried using the Fluent API .HasAnnotation("BackingField", "_id") method in your context's OnModelCreating override?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug, because it works if you provide `public`, `internal` or `protected` (but not `private` or none) setter for the `Id` property, or if you specify the key of the **derived** entity explicitly via Fluent API

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().HasKey(e => e.Id);
```

which of course defeats the whole purpose of using the base class property.

You might consider reporting it to EF Core [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework).

Comment: I don't see how this is a bug.  As you pointed out, it doesn't work (and can't work) if the property has no setter.  And in the OP's code, the property has no setter.  It shouldn't work.